# $f\in\mathscr L([0,\infty),\lambda)$ with $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq 0$

Tags: continuity, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in \mathscr L([0,\infty),\lambda)$. Show, that there exists a continous function $f$ with $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq 0$.
I thought about a function $f_n=\chi_{B_{1/n^2}}$ and $f=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$. But is this acounterexample and is it continous?

Comment: Draw small triangles around integer points with height $1$.

Comment: I don't know how this helps me

Comment: I am describing the graph of a function with required properties.

Comment: Is the limit required to exist, or do we just not want to converge to $0$?

Comment: It is not required to exist